# Solr auto complete with ngram ignore spaces and upper latters

Tags: solr, sitecore

I have title string fields:

```
word 111
word 222
word XYZ
word YNX
```

I have next settings in solr for index it

```xml
<fieldType name="auto_complete" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
         <analyzer type="index">
             <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
             <!-- <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" /> -->
             <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
              generateWordParts="1" 
              generateNumberParts="1"
              catenateWords="1"
              catenateNumbers="1"
              catenateAll="1"
              splitOnCaseChange="1"
              splitOnNumerics="1"
              preserveOriginal="1" />
             <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
             <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="40" />
             <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^\w\d\*æøåÆØÅ ])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
         </analyzer>
         <analyzer type="query">
             <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
              <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
              generateWordParts="0" 
              generateNumberParts="0"
              catenateWords="0"
              catenateNumbers="0"
              catenateAll="0"
              splitOnCaseChange="0"
              splitOnNumerics="0"
        />
             <!-- <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
             <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" /> -->
             <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
             <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^\w\d\*æøåÆØÅ ])" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
         </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I can search via it and 
I am getting results if type
*wo,wor, word, 11, 111* etc.
but I can't get results if type
*word XYZ* or just XYZ 
how to activate option to use spaces and upper case for auto complete ?

Comment: How did you configure the solr auto suggestion feature ?

Comment: good question. I don't have it at all. How it should be ?

Comment: Please go through this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester